# Understanding CAGradient locations?

Tags: ios, calayer, gradient

i am creating a simple bar with a CAGradient layer. i have 6 colors that i want to be spread equally on the layer.

```
NSMutableArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:.95] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:153.0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:.95]CGColor],
                         (id)[ [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:.95]CGColor],
                         (id)[ [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:.95]CGColor],
                         (id)[ [UIColor blackColor]CGColor],nil];

NSMutableArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0.14],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0.28],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0.42],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0.56],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0.70],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0.84],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:1.0],nil];
```

and implement them with :

```
 gradientLayer_.colors =colors;
 gradientLayer_.locations=locations;
```

But I am getting a totally black bar. when i remove the locations i see the gradient perfectly but it is not divided well.

I feel that i don't understand the locations well.

any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are using `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` on several of the stop location definitions. Use `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:]`.
2. The number of colors should be the same as the number of stops. You have 5 colors and 8 stop locations. Either add 3 colors or remove 3 stop locations.

Comment: Thanks. you know i am finding that in 90 percent of the cases it os always a very simple solution.